# Can't read a text file in java (consider as empty file)

Tags: java, file, text

I would like to do an app for myself that will tell me the movies I've seen or not.
First problem, in the prototype, I have a text file in which I have put some title of movies.
But the scanner I use just consider the file as empty.
To me it should work an I have no idea where to search.
Thanks for your help. :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    boolean trouve = false;
    System.out.println("Entrer le film a chercher");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = input.nextLine();
    Scanner films = new Scanner(new File("C:/Films.txt"));

    while (films.hasNextLine() == true) {
        String line = films.nextLine();
        if (line.contains(word)) {
            trouve = true;
            System.out.println("ok");
        }
    }
    if (trouve) {
        System.out.println("Le film est présent");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Le film n'est pas présent");
    }
    System.out.println("Continuer ( entrer ) ou quitter");
    word = input.next();
}
```

Comment: What does your txt file look like?

Comment: I tried with self made text file and it seems to work. On the other hand I'd like to point out that you are comparing true/false to true to obtain true/false :v (films.hasNextLine() == true)

Comment: Make sure your filename and directory are correct when you initialize your scanner

Comment: I also tested your method and it works for me. Maybe try a different path (like Desktop) and move your file there?

Comment: "films.hasNextLine() == true" should bei replaced with "films.hasNextLine()". That is not the problem but bad style. Comparing a bollean to a bollean is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class HaveFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            boolean trouve = false;
            System.out.println("Entrer le film a chercher");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String word = input.nextLine();
            Scanner films = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));

            while (films.hasNextLine() == true) {
                String line = films.nextLine();
                if (line.contains(word)) {
                    trouve = true;
                    System.out.println("ok");
                }
            }
            if (trouve) {
                System.out.println("Le film est présent");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Le film n'est pas présent");
            }
            System.out.println("Continuer ( entrer ) ou quitter");
            word = input.next();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and it appeared to work just fine. I compiled then ran as:

```
java HaveFile HaveFile.java
```

and when it prompted, I said "input" as that appears in the text.

I suspect your basic problem is that your file doesn't actually exist. Are you sure C:/Films.txt is there? I'm on a Mac, not Windows, so I can't comment on the windows-specific portion of this.

Comment: How confident are you that file exists? And is the correct file format on a windows machine C:/Filename or is it C:\Filename? You can do File foo = new File("...") and then if (foo.exists()) to tell you something. You could use "C:/" as your file and ask if it's a directory, then query the contents.

Comment: Your solution probably works but not on my computer (so sad). I checked the file name and the path to it. The problem I think is that it does not enter the while loop.

Comment: You where actualy right, it is "C:\" but the problem still persist. I did ask if the file was existing and it exists the directory also exists.

Comment: If it;s C:\ then what you really need in your string is C:\\Filename because the first \ needs to escape the second \. Otherwise C interprets the name as C: \F (whatever a \F might be in a C string) ilename.

Comment: Well I deleted my file and created an new one and now it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Thank a lot for your help. But if you know what have happened, I'd like to know :)